# Why can we cool one species Fermionic gas in evaporative cooling?

Tags: atomic-physics, fermions

I met a problem in the evaporative cooling of Fermions. If I want to cool Fermionic gas to a very low temperature, I need to let s-wave scattering happen in the evaporative cooling process.

However, because of Pauli exclusion principle, two identical Fermions can not be in the same quantum state. So when two Fermions collide together, the differential cross section looks like:

$$
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=|f(\theta)-f(\pi-\theta)|^2
$$

This make cross section vanish. Now I searched some papers that this issue can be resolved by using different spin states (e.g. $^{40}K$ with $F=9/2, m_F=9/2,7/2$ in magnetic trap)

Even though I put two hyperfine states of the same species together, Pauli principle still applies here. Then the cross section is still zero.

So, some experiments proved that it works but Pauli principle says it does not. I don't understand which road of thought goes wrong.